# Syntax error near "'SELECT s.id AS 'Salarie.id', s.nom AS 'Salarie.nom', COALESCE(p' on line 1

Tags: laravel

I have 3 tables, salaries table `salaries(id, name)` and `pointages table pointages(id, datep, salarie_id, sold)` and avances `table avances(id, datea, montantA, salarie_id)`.

table salaries

```
Id  name
1   kamal   
2   imad
```

pointages table

```
id  datep       Salarie_id  sold
1   11/03/2020      1        120
2   05/03/2020      1        100
3   06/03/2020      2        50
4   07/03/2020      2        20
```

avances table

```
id  datea         montantA    Salarie_id
1   11/03/2020    120          1
2   02/03/2020    50           1
```

by these 3 tables I want to recover `salaries.id` and `salaries.name` and `sum (pointages.sold)` and `sum (avances.montantA)` like this

```
Salarie.id  Salaries.nom    Sum(sold)   Sum(montantA)
1              kamal           220          170
2              imad            70           0
```

I have a mysql request allows to recover the correct data and sums, I want to write this function by laravel (query engine) but I don't know how then I put my request directly in the `etatq1u function` of controller but it gives me this error: `Erreur de syntaxe près de "'SELECT s.id AS 'Salarie.id', s.nom AS 'Salarie.nom', COALESCE(p' à la ligne 1 ...`
**SalarieController.php**

```
public function etatq1u(request $request){
$dataP = DB::select('"SELECT 
            s.id AS Salarie.id, 
            s.nom AS Salarie.nom, 
            COALESCE(p.somme, 0) AS SUM(sold), 
             COALESCE(a.somme, 0) AS SUM(montantA 
            FROM 
            Salaries s 
             LEFT JOIN (SELECT SUM(sold) AS somme, salarie_id FROM pointages GROUP BY salarie_id) AS p ON p.salarie_id = s.id
             LEFT JOIN (SELECT SUM(montantA) AS somme, salarie_id FROM avances GROUP BY salarie_id) AS a ON a.salarie_id = s.id
            GROUP BY s.id, p.salarie_id, a.salarie_id"');
            return response($dataP);
}
```

Comment: Bonjour. Comme tu utilise Laravel, peut tu utiliser Eloquent https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent pour tes requetes?

Comment: check the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60660069/sum-left-join-multiple-tables-laravel6/60670945#60670945